# Dart import a package you have created

Tags: dart, import, package

I have some code that i want to use between two projects. I would like to break this out into a package and import it into other projects/packages that need it. When i try to import a locally created package, I get a "The target URI doesnt exist" error. What do i need to do? Is there a path environment variable that dart checks to find local packages? Do i need to publish my package to pub.dev and use "dart pub add"? (I really would not prefer this)
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages

Answer (score 0):

The `dependencies` section of `pubspec.yaml` supports, along with the pub.dev and Git options, a `path` option.

*Path dependencies* are [documented on the Dart website](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages).

For example:

```yaml
dependencies:
  hosted_package: ^1.0.0
  local_package:
    path: ../my_local_package
```